# Where did everything go?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I was moving files around when I accidentally mistype the command
`mv misc/* *` instead of `mv misc/* .`  where did everything go, and how can I get it back, the misc folder is gone?

Comment: what was your current working directory at the time

Comment: /home/kruegerdata/Gracilaria_GBS_data/assembled_reads inside the folder there are 2 subfolders misc and tmp, I was trying to move the contents of misc/ one folder up to assembled_reads

Comment: look for * inside that folder

Comment: where would it be? would it have created the folder during the move?

Comment: yup, inside the folder you were in, when you ran the command.

Comment: if what you say is all correct it should be here :/home/kruegerdata/Gracilaria_GBS_data/assembled_reads

Comment: I'm just curious: what shell were you using when this happened?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think everything went to the last object returned by the second `*`. If it wasn't a directory, you would have got an error.

Go to the directory where you run `mv` and invoke `echo *`. Then look into the last directory that is printed.

---

What I think has happened is as follows:

Your `mv misc/* *` was expanded by your shell to

```
mv multiple-objects-from-within-misc multiple-objects-from-within-the-current-directory
```

The last object in this sequence is the target where your files and directories went. Based on your comments I guess it was the `tmp` directory. Unfortunately objects from `misc` and from the upper directory are now in `tmp` altogether (and with everything that had already been there) and you cannot easily tell which one came from where.

Comment: echo * showed the names of every file but not where the where located

Answer (score 2):

If you run ls, you'll likely notice you have a directory now called `*`

Yes, you renamed it to `*`!

To get it back, use mv again but you'll need to escape the *.

`mv ./\* ./misc`

The \ before * escapes it, meaning it's treated as a literal * instead of trying to match something else.

If you can't remember where you were within the file system, use `find / -name '\*' 2>/dev/null` to locate them.

Comment: beat me to it... :P

Comment: This worked help me find the files the were put in the last folder I was using tmp

Comment: @user1952312 are you saying you can't find them? try running `find / -name '\*'`

Comment: Strange. I have just recreated the issue on my Ubuntu and it worked according to my answer, not yours. There is no `*` directory. Yet your answer is accepted and upvoted. Now I'm wondering: what am I missing? Under what conditions will it work your way?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski it'll depend what shell you have, that's likely why.

Comment: I'm using the fish shell environment and and iterm terminal enumerator for context

Comment: For the record: I've checked `bash`, `dash`, `sh` (provided by `dash` executable), `zsh`, `csh` and `fish`. None of them created `*` directory.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I agree with your solution. Either "*" resolves to something and everything is moved to it, or the curent directpry is empty, `*` remains `*`, and mv screams `mv: target '*' is not a directory`. The only way to obtain `*` requires that 1) the current directory is empty and 2) the source directory contains one single file.

Comment: @xenoid You're right, this scenario *will* create `*` directory. Thank you for this input. I'm glad I didn't downvote this answer rashly, it may be useful in general. (In this case, however, we knew from the start the current directory was not empty – `misc` was there.)